# Why does `predict` in R when using a glmnet model return a high dimensional prediction?

Tags: r, machine-learning, glm, glmnet

Here's a small example reproducing the issue:

```
model <- glmnet(matrix(rnorm(3*100), 100, 3), rbernoulli(100))
preds <- predict(model, matrix(rnorm(3*100), 100, 3))
dim(preds)
# 100 60
```

But since the predicted variable is bernoulli, I'd expect the output to be either 1 or 2 dimensional (probability of `1`, or probability of each class).

I've looked at the documentation for `glmnet` and for `predict` but I can't find anything that describes this behavior. What I'm looking for is to simply fit a model to some training data, and then compute class probabilities so that I can compute AUC.

I'm mainly asking about this behavior because this does not happen if for example I use the rpart package together with `predict`, that is for example

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(matrix(rnorm(3*100), 100, 3), rbernoulli(100)))
model <- rpart(X4 ~ ., df)
length(predict(model, data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3*100), 100, 3))))
# 100, as expected
```

Coming from Python, I'm finding a lot of this confusing, since the `predict` function seems to be general, though it obviously behaves differently for two binary classifiers.

Comment: looks like you are getting predictions for mutliple values of lambda -- if you want one prediction you need to select one  lambda value i.e. cv.glmnet

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the relevant docs are not at `?predict`, but at [`?predict.glmnet`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-16/topics/predict.glmnet). Based on user20650's comment, the `s` parameter seems relevant!

Comment: `?predict.glmnet` provides `predict(object, newx, s = NULL,
type=c("link","response","coefficients","nonzero","class"), exact = FALSE, newoffset, ...)`. Then, for `s`: `Value(s) of the penalty parameter lambda at which predictions are required. Default is the entire sequence used to create the model. ` Because you have not supplied `s`, it is by default running `predict` on each lambda produced by `glmnet`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, tho I'm a bit confused. Shouldn't the lambda be determined at training?

Comment: @JakubArnold As mentioned in the first statement, you should use `cv.glmnet` instead of `glmnet` to determine the best lambda.

Answer (score 1):

In R, you would find many examples in which you get an output based on dimension/ class etc. of your input to a function.

For `glmnet`, by default you supply a range of lambda's:

lambda (i.e. shrinkage factor) is a hyper parameter for regularized regression model (glmnet).

```
set.seed(1)
model <- glmnet(matrix(rnorm(3*100), 100, 3), purrr::rbernoulli(100))
preds <- predict(model, matrix(rnorm(3*100), 100, 3))

dim(preds)
#[1] 100  61

length(model$lambda)
[1] 61
```

You need to tune it based on a desired performance measure, to find the optimal/ best value for your model. Once you have it, you can use it to get final predictions. Something like:

```
model <- glmnet(matrix(rnorm(3*100), 100, 3), purrr::rbernoulli(100), 
                lambda = 0.19)        # assuming its an optimal value
preds <- predict(model, matrix(rnorm(3*100), 100, 3))

dim(preds)
# [1] 100   1
```

while `rpart` doesn't require a hyper parameter by default as it fits a complete tree without pruning which is equivalent of supplying a single hyper parameter value that corresponds to fitting data till the leaf nodes. Therefore you obtain a single set of predictions. The downside of using this current classifier being that its not generalized.

Therefore if you are shifting from python to R for a applied machine learning tasks its best to utilize the ***[caret package](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html)*** its a homogeneous framework combining multiple statistical models under a unified modeling approach.